Time taken by a monkey to type a string
This is a question from Mark Joshi's book:

A monkey types letters from the alphabet plus the space bar with equal probability at the rate of one a second. How long would it take him to type the string option pricing

My attempt:
First, I attempted for only 2 letters: op 
Then, we will have three states: $S_0, S_1$, and $S_2$. To set the transition probabilities, if we're at state $S_1$ i.e. we already have an 'o', then will we have a transition from $S_1$ to $S_1$? Because, if we get o after o, that means we don't have to start the game all over again. Will it be so or we will have no such loop? Considering such a loop exists, I get the following three equations:
\begin{align}
E_{0,2} &= 1 + \frac{1}{27}E_{1,2} + \frac{26}{27}E_{0,2} \\
E_{1,2} &= 1 + \frac{1}{27}E_{2,2} + \frac{1}{27}E_{1,2} + \frac{25}{27}E_{0,2}
\end{align}
Solving these equations, I get: $E_{0,2} = 27^2 = 729$ 
Python simulation gives $727.4805$ for $10000$ simulations.
Similarly, for the word opt, I got $E_{0,3} = 27^3 = 19683$ 
Python simulation gives $19754.962$ for $1000$ simulations.
Is this correct?
Assuming it is, can we generalize this to the word option pricing and conclude that $E[N] = 27^l$, where $N$ is the number of keyboard hits and $l$ is the length of the string including the space?

Hint: try finding the time to write oo. How does it differ from writing op?

@isaacg I am confused now. If we have oo, we don't have a self-loop and hence, it gives $E_{0,2}=28$. For op, it comes out to be $E_{0,2}=27^2$ (taking a loop back to $S_1$ where we got o) So, can we say this formula does not apply when we have repetitions? Because, once we reach $S_4$, we are at i, now the next alphabet is o, but we also have taken into account a transition back to $S_1$ which is also an o

You have moved ahead by one step, whether the letter was o or something else, but it is not as if you have got a bonus. If you don't get n next, you will be back to the original o, i.e. the start.

Re your method, I'm not very clear about your notation. What does $E(0,2)$ exactly signify ?

@trueblueanil But if you see above, $S_1$ is the state whose corresponding term $E_{1,2}$ we include in each equation as it represents transition back to o (beginning of the word). Now, when I am at i which is state $S_4$, as the equations are setup above, there will be one transition from $S_4 \to S_5$ (i.e. we chose the correct o), then there will be a transition from $S_4 \to S_0$ (i.e. when we get anything other than o), and there will be a transition from $S_4 \to S_1$ (i.e. this time we go to the starting o). Isn't it wrong or won't it affect the dynamics of the overall system?

@trueblueanil In standard notation, if you have $k$-states where state $k$ is the absorbing state, then $\mu_i$ is the expected number of steps to reach the absorbing state starting from state $S_i$. In my notation, the second index in subscript is the total number of states and $\mu$ is replaced by $E$. Hence, $E_{i,k}$ means expected number of tosses to get to absorbing state $S_k$ from state $S_i$.

I understand your notation. Regarding the intermediate o, the starting state is when nothng useful has been tossed. o  is the first useful state, but also an intermediate state. From intermediate o, you can either move forward to n, or to starting state (nothing useful ) or to o which is  not the intermediate o but is the first useful state. I hope it is clear now.

I see that you have been asking lots of questions recently without accepting (tickmarking) all but one.. Are all other answers useless, so to say ?

See this question.

There is a  way of arriving at a solution for such problems using an algorithm by Conway (Penney's Game fame) which is palpably simpler than using first step analysis for such problems
It involves assigning a $Y$ or $N$ matching first entry with last, first two entries with last two, and so on, writing $Y$ for match and $N$ for non-match.
For option pricing, the successive findings are:

$1: o - g, N$

$2: op - ng, N$

$3: opt - ing, N$

$4: opti - cing, N$

$5: optio - icing, N$

$6: option - ricing, N$

$7: option( ) - pricing, N$ and so on. with a $Y$ only at the final step,

$14:$ option pricing - option pricing,Y


$$The\; formula\; is\; \Bbb{E}[N] =\sum_{L=1}^{14}27^{L}$$
only for L's having a $Y$ = $27^{14}$

It is unclear where you're using the summation index $i$. Going by your notation, the expectation $\mathbb{E}[N]$ becomes $14\cdot 27^L$

Summation is only for those indices where a Y is noted. Here it is only at $i=14,$

@Sid: Note that being at the "intermediate" o does not give any special advantage as you can return to the "first useful " o from any letter with the same probability.

@Sid: Finally, re the summation, suppose you want to compute # of throws to get $3$ consecutive $6's$, because you will get $YYY$ by Conway method, here the summation will be $6^1+6^2+6^3 =258$ So your hypthesis of $(1/27)^L$ won't work for all letter sequences.

Consider the infinite product space of all one-sided sequences over 27 symbols (the 26 letters and a space), each symbol chosen independently with probability $\frac{1}{27}$. Denote a generic element of this space as $\omega$. We define a shift operator $T$ that sends $\omega$ to $T\omega$ by discarding $\omega_1$ and sliding everything left so that $\omega_2$ starts at position 1.
Let $A$ be the set of all infinite sequences whose first 13 symbols match exactly the string "option pricing". Because each of the 13 symbols is uniformly chosen from 27 possibilities, the product measure $\mu(A)$ of $A$ is $(\frac{1}{27})^{13}$.
By Kac’s lemma, if a set $A$ in an ergodic probability space has measure $\mu(A)$, then almost every trajectory (under the shift) returns to $A$ infinitely often and the expected return time is exactly $\frac{1}{\mu(A)}$.
In this setting, "return time" to $A$ in the product space translates into "how long until the typed sequence of characters first matches 'option pricing' starting at some position." Since $\mu(A) = (\frac{1}{27})^{13}$, the expected time to see the string "option pricing" for the first time is therefore $27^{13}$.

Including the stroke for space bar, there are 14 symbols.

Where does your argument fail for harder strings like "abracadabra"?

What result does your  method give   for the simple string ABAB ?
